# How to decode all entities except html entities

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode

I have a string that has special letters like "`á`" and htmlcode like "`<input type='text' />`". When I store this string in my DB I use: `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES);`.
The problem is when I output the text, I use `html_entity_decode($string_from_db, ENT_QUOTES)` and all the entities I have in the database like "`&aacute;`" for the letters and "`<input type='text' title="LA1&qu...`" for the htmlcode gets converted. So my output will show the "`á`" letter and a text field which is not normal. I want the letter to be like that but for the field I want to show the code "`<input type='text' />`" not the actual field.

I need this for a multilingual site with alot of user input, so I need to be able to process the special letter properly but also protect for bad input. Any advice is greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems I figured it out .... at least for now. Here's what I'm doing:

1. The text submitted by the user i sanitize it with:

   ```
   function sanitize_form_input($string) {
       $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
       return $string;
   }
   ```
2. Got page encoding, php encoding, html encoding, mysql encoding ... and any other possible thing with encoding set to UTF-8.
3. Output the text with:

   ```
   function sanitize_db_output($string) {
       return htmlentities(stripslashes($string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
   }
   ```

Please let me know if this is a wrong way to do it.

Comment: Why are you doing stripslashes? And won't your code also show all characters as entities, as you said you didn't want in a comment to my answer? I think the update to my answer should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

You could just do an additional `htmlspecialchars` after `html_entity_decode`; that function will only convert the characters which have a special function in HTML to their entity:

```
htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($string_from_db, ENT_QUOTES), ENT_QUOTES)
```

That should take care that the resulting string has no unencoded html characters. Of course, performancewise, that's probably not the best solution, but it's simple!

Comment: that won't help me because it will convert the letters also :|